# Python on ubuntu does not recognize current package

Tags: python, ubuntu

I had a python project structured like this:

```
--prj
----app
------__init__.py
------mod1.py
------run.py
----README.md
```

and run.py's content is

```
from app.mod1 import *
```

when I run in windows it works perfectly fine.
In Ubuntu, it reported that "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'"

the start argument is simple "cd ...prj/app; python3.6 run.py"

I tried to find out the sys.path, by "python3.6 -c 'import sys;print(sys.path)'"
the result is

```
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Why would that happen?

Comment: what is `XXX` in `cd XXX` exactly?

Comment: where is `app.py` located?

Comment: sry for the disturbance, i have reedited the post

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because the name of your python script is the same than the module name. Try to rename app.py, for instance to app_main.py and it should work.

Comment: sorry for the disturbance , this is a typing mistask, the entrypoint file is run.py

Comment: OK, I see. Your run.py script which uses app package should be located a level above the app folder. If you run inside the app folder the `from app.mod1 import *`statement tries to search an app subfolder of the app folder, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you I feel is wrong is that every folder and sub folder should have **init**.py for packages to work in python which isn't present in the app and project folder.

also store the package in the '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload' and try importing the package.